# Regex for URL to sites

Tags: regex, sitemap, regex-negation, regex-greedy, regedit

I have two URLs with the patterns:

1.http://localhost:9001/f/

2.http://localhost:9001/flight/

I have a site filter which redirects to the respective sites if the regex matches. I tried the following regex patterns for the 2 URLs above:

http?://localhost[^/]*/f[^flight]/*.*

http?://localhost[^/]*/flight/*.*

Both URLS are getting redirected to the first site, as both URLs are matched by the first regex.

I have tried http?://localhost[^/]*/[f]/*.* also for the 1st url. I am Unable to get what am i missing . I feel that this regex should not accept any thing other than "f", but it is allowing "flight" as well.

Please help me by pointing the mistake i have done.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Where should each URL be directed to? What happens when you try http?://localhost[^/]/f/.* VS  http?://localhost[^/]/flight/.* ?

Comment: each URL would be redirected to different sites. My urls are 1.[link]localhost:9001/f/ 2.[link]localhost:9001/flight/ . i have a site filter shich compares with the regex patterns and redirect to the respective sites

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep things simple:

```
.*/f(/[^/]*)?$
```

vs

```
.*/flight(/[^/]*)?$
```

Adding `?` before `$` makes the trailing slash with optional path term optional.

Comment: first regex is failing for the following URL localhost:9001/f . user may enter the url with or with out slash i have tried .*/[f]$ its not working did i do anything wrong

Comment: This will work only for '/f' or '/f/' . '/f' is a context path of url so there can be anything after this like 'localhost:9001/f/myPage' or 'localhost:9001/f/yourPage/'. I have tried '/f/?$.*' still not working. If i use '/f/?$*.*' its accepting 2nd url as well

Comment: @phani I've edited again. In future, it would help to provide various matching and non-matching examples

Answer (score 0):

The first one will be caught with following regex;

`/^http:[\/]{2}localhost:9001\/f[^light]$/`

The other one will be disallowed and can be found with following regex

`/^http:[\/]{2}localhost:9001\/flight\/$/`

Answer (score 0):

You regex has several issues: 1) `p?` means *optional* `p` (`htt://` will match), 2) `[^/]` will only match `:` in your URLs since it will only capture 1 character (and you have a port number), 3) `[^light]` is a negated character class that means *any character that is not `l`, `i`, `g`, `h`, or `t`*.

So, if you want to only capture `localhost` URLs, you'd better [use this regex](https://regex101.com/r/rY0fV9/1) for the 1st site:

```
http://localhost[^/]*/f/.*
```

And [this one](https://regex101.com/r/rY0fV9/2) for the second

```
http://localhost[^/]*/flight/.*
```

Please also bear in mind that depending on where you use the regexps, your actual input may or may not include either the protocol.

Answer (score 0):

These should work for you:

```
http[s]{0,1}:\/\/localhost:[0-9]{4}\/f\/
http[s]{0,1}:\/\/localhost:[0-9]{4}\/flight\/
```

You can see it working [here](https://regex101.com/r/uF4aQ0/1)